# Boolean Indexing with Pandas isn't working for me

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm getting some strange behaviour in pandas when using Boolean indexing, and I don't understand what's going wrong.

With a DataFrame `data` that contains a column `RSTAR` of `Float` values, among others, I'm getting the following when I try to do boolean indexing:

```
rejection_list = list( data[ (data.RSTAR == 0) | (~ np.isfinite(data.RSTAR)) ].loc[:,'NAME'] )
```

Gives me an error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The following on the other hand:

```
booll = (data.RSTAR == 0) | (~ np.isfinite(data.RSTAR))
rejection_list2 = list(data[booll].loc[:,'NAME'])
```

Works fine. As far as I can tell, these two expressions should do the exact same thing. So why does the bottom one work, but not the top one?

---

UPDATE: Still don't understand what's going on, I looked further into it and here's what happened:

I tried to slice the `data` DataFrame so that I could post it on here. So with `data = data.loc[:5,:]` I get the same exact error.  However, with `data = data.loc[:5, ['RSTAR', 'NAME']]` I get no error and it works as it should.

I'm not sure how to post the entire `data` array here since it's got lots of columns, but the column names are:

```
data.columns
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'NAME', 'RADIUS', 'RUPPER', 'RLOWER', 'UR', 'MASS',
       'MASSUPPER', 'MASSLOWER', 'UMASS', 'A', 'AUPPER', 'ALOWER', 'UA',
       'RSTAR', 'RSTARUPPER', 'RSTARLOWER', 'URSTAR', 'TEFF', 'TEFFUPPER',
       'TEFFLOWER', 'UTEFF', 'ECC', 'LUM', 'RERRMAX', 'LOG_FLUX', 'FLUX'],
      dtype='object')
```

So I can't see any duplication or anything. I just don't understand what's wrong.

---

UPDATE 2: It got more confusing. So I went into pdb again, like so:

```
pdb.set_trace() ###
rejection_list = list(data[ (data.RSTAR == 0) | (~ np.isfinite(data.RSTAR)) ].loc[:,'NAME'])
```

And keeping the same `data`, I copy and pasted the exact statement above: `rejection_list = list(data[ (data.RSTAR == 0) | (~ np.isfinite(data.RSTAR)) ].loc[:,'NAME'])` and it worked **while in pdb mode**. However, as soon as I click `c` to continue out of pdb into the next line, the **same** line I just successfully executed in pdb, it gives me the error again. I'm at a complete loss here. Is it something to do with a cache? I opened a new Terminal but it's still giving me the same problem.

---

UPDATE 3: Tried it with isnull() and notnull() and same problem.

```
booll = (data.RSTAR==0) | (data.RSTAR.isnull())
data[booll]
```

works, but the following doesn't:

```
rejection_list = list(data[ (data.RSTAR == 0) | (data.RSTAR.isnull()) ].loc[:,'NAME'])
```

---

UPDATE 4: The opposite works with no problem: `data = data[(data.RSTAR != 0) & (data.RSTAR.notnull())]`.

---

EDIT: To make it clear, it seems to be the case that when I execute the command by typing it in directly in pdb, it works, for the small and large dataframes. However, when I just let the script run, then it doesn't work for small or large.

Comment: Can you post raw data and code to reproduce this, this to me should work and I can't reproduce it

Comment: Hang on I got lunch now. I tried the same type of Boolean indexing but with a simple 3x3 DataFrame and it actually worked. So I can't reproduce either, it only doesn't work in the example I provided above. At the end of the day though, even if something is wrong with my data (I'll recheck that), I can't see why my first piece of code doesn't work, but the second does.

Comment: I updated my question, still the same problem, but now there's another inconsistency with how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use one line solution with pandas function [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
rejection_list = data.ix[(data.RSTAR == 0) | (data.RSTAR.notnull()) , 'NAME'].tolist()
```

or:

```
rejection_list = data.loc[(data.RSTAR == 0) | (data.RSTAR.notnull()) , 'NAME'].tolist()
```

I try reproduce your error, but all works correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'RSTAR':[0,2,-np.inf, np.nan,np.inf],
                     'NAME':[4,5,6,7,10]})

print (data)
   NAME     RSTAR
0     4  0.000000
1     5  2.000000
2     6      -inf
3     7       NaN
4    10       inf

rejection_list = list( data[ (data.RSTAR == 0) | (~ np.isfinite(data.RSTAR)) ].loc[:,'NAME'])
print (rejection_list)
[4, 6, 7, 10]

booll = (data.RSTAR == 0) | (~ np.isfinite(data.RSTAR))
rejection_list2 = list(data[booll].loc[:,'NAME'])
print (rejection_list2)
[4, 6, 7, 10]

rejection_list3 = data.ix[(data.RSTAR == 0) | (data.RSTAR.notnull()) , 'NAME'].tolist()
print (rejection_list2)
[4, 6, 7, 10]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants an explanation of why the first code snippet fails, not so much how to achieve what they want as they already have a solution

Comment: @Edchum, thank you. But it looks like both solutions are same, what do you think? But I try test it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this so the OP needs to post an example

Comment: @EdChum - I check it twice and try sample, but it looks like all work nice .

Comment: As I said in the comment above, I'm also having trouble reproducing the error. It seems to only happen in a very specific case but I don't understand why. I updated by question with some new info.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I used isnull() and notnull() :(

Comment: So, what is your version of pandas? `pd.show_versions()`

Comment: pandas 0.18.0 I can post the entire output if you want

Comment: I dont understand it. It is very weird. And what about solution with `rejection_list = data.ix[(data.RSTAR == 0) | (data.RSTAR.notnull()) , 'NAME'].tolist()` ? Does it work?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. I'm going to post this on the pandas github, maybe they can help. I've been thinking about it and I can't figure out what could logically be wrong. Maybe there's something with the way pandas does boolean indexing which changes the way it combines the two boolean series. Anyway, thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: One thing, it faild with small dataframe or only with big one?

Comment: And is possible share your data via csv by dropbox, google docs or wetransfer? I would like check if it works for me. Maybe your pandas installation is broken...

Comment: I sent you an email. Also, I'll update the question with this new info: it happens for small and large DataFrames when outside of pdb. However, as I said above, when I enter pdb and start playing around with the DataFrame, whatever I do (even if I don't change it at all) then it actually works using the same exact command.